# CakePHP: Bookmarker tutorial file missing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am doing my first steps with CakePHP (version 3). Installation and settings went perfectly well for me. I decide to follow the examples provided in the documentation and I followed the first one which is [Bookmarker tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html).

Everything went fine until the **Creating the View** section where it says *In src/Template/Bookmarks/tags.ctp put the following content:*. The problem is that I do not find **tags.ctp** under **src/Template/Bookmarks/**.

What is wrong with my situation? Or is that tutorial erroneous?

Comment: just create tags.ctp

Comment: @Salines thank you for the feedback. But are you sure of that? Because there is a folder named Tags under src/Template. Have you experienced this problem?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, read tutorial again. You create method tags inside Bookmarks Controller, so you need to have tags.ctp for that method

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, yes, your first comment was RIGHT !!! It works now !!!! Thank you very much @Salines